# finding nearest positive semi-definite correlation matrix

Tags: algorithm, r, optimization, matrix, correlation

Is there an R function or DLL that calculates a nearest positive semi-definite correlation matrix?

Finding the nearest positive semi-definite matrix is a well-documented common problem in portfolio construction.

[NAGS](http://www.nag.co.uk/IndustryArticles/Nearest_Correlation_Matrix.pdf) includes a function but the library requires a license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `nearcor` in the [`sfsmisc`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sfsmisc/index.html) package uses the same algorithm as that NAG routine you link to.

Comment: That was fast! Thank you I will take a look

Comment: A couple more are nearPD and posdefify.  A clue about these is in: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Re-always-about-positive-definite-matrix-td3260703.html which I found on Rseek (though I had a headstart about knowing what I was looking for).